# aurelia-validation: validation errors are not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia. I want to pass validation to my custom element.

The validation does work, but it does not show the validation errors correctly on the screen.

I have 2 problems:

- There is no validation before i submit the form
- After submitting the form. I get always one validation error even when I fill everything correctly, the validation error is 'is required'.(I took a [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJi89.png), There are eight characters)

welcome.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./my-element"></require>
    <my-element name.bind="myName" val.bind="validation"></my-element>
</template>
```

welcome.js

```
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class Welcome {
  myName = 'the name';

  static inject = [Validation]
  constructor(validation) {
      this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensure('name')
                  .isNotEmpty()
                  .hasMinLength(3)
                  .hasMaxLength(10);
    }
}
```

my-element.html

```
<template> 
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="save()"  validate.bind="val">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>name</label>
            <input type="text" value.bind="name"><br/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

my-element.js

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyElement{
    @bindable name;
    @bindable val;

    static inject = [Element];
     constructor(element){
        this.element = element;
    }

    save(){
        this.val.validate()
                .then( () => {
                    alert('correct');
                }).catch(error => {
                    alert('not correct');
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caveats**

To get the validation messages we have to trick the validation into thinking the element model is the viewmodel we have set up the validation. This probably shouldn't work, and probably won't work in the future - see http://blog.durandal.io/2016/03/18/preparing-for-infrastructure-update/#validation

First in **welcome.js** change the `ensure('name')` to `ensure('myName')` as that is the name of the property you are validating.

```
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class Welcome {
  myName = 'the name';
  static inject = [Validation]
  constructor(validation) {
      this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensure('myName')
                  .isNotEmpty()
                  .hasMinLength(3)
                  .hasMaxLength(10);
    }
}
```

Second, in **welcome.html** set the binding from `name.bind='myName'` to `my-name.two-way='myName'`. This will ensure the view model has been updated with the current value before validating.

```
<template>
    <require from="./my-element"></require>
    <my-element my-name.two-way="myName" val.bind="validation"></my-element>
</template>
```

Third, in **my-element.js** change your bindable from `name` to `myName`

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyElement{
    @bindable myName;
    @bindable val;

    static inject = [Element];
     constructor(element){
        this.element = element;
    }

    save(){
        this.val.validate()
                .then( () => {
                    alert('correct');
                }).catch(error => {
                    alert('not correct');
                });
    }
}
```

And finally update my-element.html accordingly

```
<template> 
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="save()"  validate.bind="val">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>name</label>
            <input type="text" value.bind="myName"><br/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. One of the two problems is solved. But unfortunately, the errors are not displayed on the screen. If the name is not valid then there is nothing displayed on the screen.

Comment: Sorry yes, I realised that after I posted. I think the problem is the validation viewstrategy doesn't recognise your element as being the control for model property. I'll have another look this evening.